# Sitecore pages to plain htmls

Tags: sitecore

We are planning to move websites hosted on Sitecore as plain htmls. I have tried all possible ways to convert them.

Is it possible to convert the Sitecore site in to HTMLs.

Comment: You mention you have tried all possible ways... would you be able to list what you have tried and what problems you encountered? People may be able to help you if the question is more specific as to the problem you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the websites, You lose a lot, personalisation, multivar testing, experience editor, content editor, analytics. And all build serverside logic, search, forms, tools. If there is only content in the website you can try a webscraper. Try http://www.httrack.com/ or https://websitedownloader.io/ or a simulair tool.